# PayPal IPN and PDT suddenly does not work anymore

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-pdt

Since this week the forwarding to our site after payment does not work anymore in production mode, while it still works within the sandbox.

Actually we use PDT for the direct forwarding and IPN as backup. For some reason the payment is not finished fully. There seems no PDT or IPN connection to be established from PayPal since beginning of this week. 
A payment from March 9th was successful, but all payments since March 11th are marked as successful on the PayPal page, but our site "does not know it", so customers don't get their accounts updated.

When trying to track the bug, I switched to the sandbox, but there everything works fine there.

Has PayPal changed something recently? (The design during payment process ist now, but I don't know since when...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The biggest downfall with PDT is the message is only sent once, where as IPN is repeatedly sent until the server responds with the correct message. You can run both, but from my experience it is very uncommon (and I build eCommerce systems for a living). Recently a lot of my company's clients who run PayPal as their payment method have come to us with a similar problem (even more so with RBS WorldPay). And the solution has been to try the following:

- Confirm that the IPN listener URL is still working and pointing to
  the right site (some people try to use one PayPal account for
  multiple sites, and change it to the 2nd site not thinking it will
  stop IPN for the 1st site).
- Make sure the latest version of the PayPal gateway is installed (if
  on OpenCart / WooCommerce / Magento / etc...). The latest version
  requires SHA-256.
- Ensure the server has SHA-256 enabled, as above PayPal is now asking
  users to make sure they have it for the hashing to work.
- Ensure that an SSL certificate is installed. It is not yet a certain requirement, but in this day and age if you don't have one, you are not likely to get many orders. Also for some strange reason it has fixed IPN for some clients.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Same server same site, I am just switching the "sandbox mode":

`if (SANDBOX == 1) { 
 $paypal['url']="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
 $paypal['fsock_open']="ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com";
 $paypal['pp_hostname']="www.sandbox.paypal.com"; // Production Site: www.paypal.com
 } else {
 $paypal['url']="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
 $paypal['fsock_open']="ssl://www.paypal.com";
 $paypal['pp_hostname']="www.paypal.com"; 
 }`
<br/><br/>
Sandbox -> works
Production -> no forwarding

Comment: This looks like part of the code you use to make the request to PayPal which is actually not likely the problem. What I was talking about with the listener URL is part of the settings in your PayPal dashboard. Have you changed the URL there?

Comment: The listener URL is for sandbox and production mode the same. 
So why is the sandbox working and the production mode not?

Comment: Do you have SHA-256 enabled? Is your IPN using SHA-256? Do you have an SSL certificate?

Comment: What do you mean with SHA-256 is enabled? 
OpenSSL is supporting SHA-256. The production server is using a signed SSL certificate, the testing server is only using a self-signed certificate.

I don't exactly know what you mean with IPN using SHA-256. The URL my server is "listening" for any IPN connection is a secure url.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, make sure that the SSL certificate is SHA-256 signed, and that the key is 2048-bit.